# pkg install using specific version of Python in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, bsd, python3

How do you 'pkg install' a package using specific version of Python in FreeBSD 11? say I want to 'pkg install' using Python 3?

Answer (score 2):

There are several versions of Python in the FreeBSD package system. There are two ways to specify a package, by name or by origin (the latter uses *category/port* notation).

The default version of Python is always called `python` or `lang/python`

The default version of Python3 is called `python3` or `lang/python3`

For a specific version of Python (for example 3.6) use `python36` or `lang/python36`.

Use `pkg search python` to see all of the names, and `pkg search -o python` to see the same results but with origins instead.